# My menu bar "menu" is disappearing what I should do to display it?

Tags: wordpress

What I miss here to set the feature "menu" **under appearance** ?

I am building new theme.

I have the folwing code witch define the menu but it disappear as you can see in the image.

Many thanks

**header.php**

```
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
                <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Main menu', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
                <?php /* Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff. */ ?>
                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>

                <?php /* Our navigation menu. If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu. The menu assigned to the primary location is the one used. If one isn't assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used. */ ?>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
            </nav><!-- #access -->
```

**function.php**

```
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
    register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu', 'twentyeleven' ) );
```

**index.php**

```
<?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>
```

[image]

Comment: do you mean you don't see the nav of wordpress or it is just something other

Comment: you right I don't see the nav "category menu" as you can see in the image. But if i active other theme like: twentyeleven, I'll see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure menu support is turned on in your Functions.php file.

```
    if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
          add_theme_support('menus');
    }
```

More info here:
http://templatic.com/news/wordpress-3-0-menu-management/